# Apply a circular page.layout to Visio

Tags: vb.net, visio

I'm currently trying to auto organise shapes that I've programmatically added to a visio page using the page.layout feature. I wish to apply a circular layout as you can do via the GUI.

Currently I have recorded the following code via macro recorder in Visio which outputs:

```
Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
UndoScopeID1 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Lay Out Shapes")
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle).FormulaForceU = "6"
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLORouteStyle).FormulaForceU = "16"
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layout
Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True
```

I have converted this for use in my VB.NET application as follows:

```
Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
    UndoScopeID1 = vApp.BeginUndoScope("Lay Out Shapes")

    Dim visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle, visPLORouteStyle As String

    vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle).FormulaForceU = "6"
    vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLORouteStyle).FormulaForceU = "16"
    vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.Layout()
    vApp.EndUndoScope(UndoScopeID1, True)
```

Note that vApp has been declared also.

This code works but applies a radial page layout rather than a circular page layout.

Does anybody know what I have to pass as the values in visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle, visPLORouteStyle to actually get it to output a circular page layout? Or is there something else that I need to do. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere easily accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the SDK notes for Visio 2003 which explain how this works:

- [Cells SRC Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/aa215160(v=office.11).aspx)
- [VisSectionIndexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/aa174168(v=office.11).aspx)
- [VisRowIndexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/aa174163(v=office.11).aspx)
- [VisCellIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/aa173677(v=office.11).aspx)

Replacing the variables with the index values from the links works nicely.

Example of solution:

```
Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
UndoScopeID1 = vApp.BeginUndoScope("Lay Out Shapes")

'vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle).FormulaForceU = "6"
'vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLORouteStyle).FormulaForceU = "16"
vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(1, 24, 8).FormulaForceU = "6"
vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(1, 24, 9).FormulaForceU = "16"
vApp.ActiveWindow.Page.Layout()
vApp.EndUndoScope(UndoScopeID1, True)
```